# vsftpd server no connect on virtual server

Tags: virtualization, connection, ftp, vsftpd

I have a virtual machine running Ubuntu in Amazon cloud server. This machine installed via APT Apache2 + PHP5 + MySql to serve my website and everything is running perfectly.

However, with no means to run an FTP server so I can update the website whenever you need. I tried both with `vsftpd` as `proftpd`, and none of them work.

The problem is that does not work or if I tenter connect locally to test remotely is also impossible.

- Using the `netstat -atpn` command can not see any reference to port 20 or 21, used by FTP.
- Any connection attempt I try to ftp returns me this message: `Connection refused`

How can I solve this? Do not want to be using sftp via SSH to upload my files.

Below the contents of my `vsftpd.conf` file:

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=NO
chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_addr_resolve=YES
pasv_max_port=12100
pasv_min_port=12000
pasv_address=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist
userlist_deny=NO
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```